# How to load an image, then wait a few seconds, then play a mp3 sound?

Tags: c#, picturebox

After pressing a button, I would like to show an image (using a  picturebox), wait a few seconds and then play a 
mp3 sound, but i dont get it to work. To wait a few seconds I use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)`. The problem is, the image always appears *after* the wait time, but I want it to show first, then wait, then play the mp3... I tried to use `WaitOnLoad = true` but it doesn't work, shouldn't it load the image first and the continue to read the next code line?

Here is the code I've tried (that doesn't work):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    pictureBox1.WaitOnLoad = true;
    pictureBox1.Load("image.jpg");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    MessageBox.Show("test");//just to test, here should be the code to play the mp3
}
```

I also tried loading the image with "LoadAsync" and put the code to wait and play the mp3 in the "LoadCompleted" event, but that doesn't work either...

Comment: You may find this answer by NoBugz to another question involving "Application.DoEvents()" useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119285/is-there-an-application-doevents-at-the-form-level/2119424#2119424

Comment: *Never* use Sleep() in the UI thread.  Use a Timer, Petar showed how.

Answer (score 6):

I would use the LoadCompleted event and start a timer with 5 sec interval once the image is loaded, so that the UI thread is not blocked:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.WaitOnLoad = false;
        pictureBox1.LoadCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(pictureBox1_LoadCompleted);
        pictureBox1.LoadAsync("image.jpg");
    }

    void pictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Timers.Timer is used as it supports multithreaded invocations
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000); 

        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);

        //set this so that the timer is stopped once the elaplsed event is fired
        timer.AutoReset = false; 

        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test"); //just to test, here should be the code to play the mp3
    }
```

Comment: OP said (on a now-deleted answer): using a timer works too, but the above [Application.DoEvents] is easier to implement

Comment: I have a problem I am using gif image. But image is show constant not moving.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `Application.DoEvents();` before the wait time? I believe that should force C# to draw the image *before* going to sleep.

Comment: OP said (on a now-deleted answer): thank you a lot for the answers !!!!! "Application.DoEvents();" is all i needed, works now :-) I cannot thank you enough, because i already spent hours to get this to work....

Comment: I have a problem I am using gif image. But image is show constant not moving.

Answer (score 2):

It works when `application.doevents()` is used.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    pictureBox1.Load("image.jpg");
    Application.DoEvents();
    pictureBox1.WaitOnLoad = true;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    MessageBox.Show("test"); //just to test, here should be the code to play the mp3
}
```